# LiveMutableData and copies update to same value?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a MutableLiveData variable in my AppRepository which is updated and contains my data. This I have no issues with. I also have the following observable to trigger a UI update with the data it holds in my `onCreateView` function:

```
viewModel.projectWithContent.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
    pwc = it
    counterList = it.counterList
})
```

When I tap either to increase or decrease the counter count and then try to push the update to my Room database, it skips it. I have the following check currently:

```
if(counterList != null) {
    try {
        for(counter: Counter in counterList!!) {
            if(counter.counter_count != pwc?.counterList!![
                pwc?.counterList!!.indexOf(counter)
            ].counter_count) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Hello")
            } else {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Goodbye")
            }
        }
    } catch(e: IndexOutOfBoundsException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

It'll always go to Goodbye.

Now. If I put the following just below `try`

```
Log.i(LOG_TAG, "PWC: ${pwc?.counterList!![0].counter_count}, " +
                        "CPWC: ${counterList!![0].counter_count}," +
                        "VMPWC: ${viewModel.projectWithContent.value?.counterList!![0].counter_count}")
```

It provides the following output:
PWC: 70, CPWC: 70,VMPWC: 70

Is this a side effect of what I'm doing or?

Thanks

Comment: It seems like expected behavior. Your log shows they are all 70. Your if/else goes to the else block since the `!=` check will be false when they are equal, so it will say "Goodbye" when they are equal. My recommendation when using if/else is to prefer arranging your branches so you can use `==` instead of `!=` so it's more intuitive. Also, look up how to use the `?.let` pattern in Kotlin. You will have much cleaner and more readable code if you use it here.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Tenfour04 says, your condition is actually checking they *don't* match, so "Goodbye" is the output when they *do* match.

If you don't mind (this is a little long), I just want to recommend some stuff because I feel like you're making life hard for yourself with all the null-checking that's going on - the logic of the code was really hard to read, and I'm guessing that's why you didn't notice the flipped logic too!

First: the `?` null safety stuff (and `!!` which is the opposite of safe, never use it unless you *know* you have good reason) is there because you have *nullable* variable types. Normally the IDE would *smart cast* them to non-null once you've done a null check (like on your first line) - but because they're `var`s, they can be changed at any time.

That means that a variable that wasn't null *before* could be *now*, so you're forced to null-check every single time you access it. But even if the types weren't nullable, because they're `var`s, they can still change, and the thing you were looking at a moment ago is something different now.

The simple solution is to just make a new variable:

```
val counters = counterList
if (counters != null) {
    ...
}

// or if you want to use one of kotlin's scope functions
counterList?.let { counters ->
    ...
}
```

Because that new one is a `val`, it's not going to change what it's pointing at! Once it's null-checked, it's *always* going to be non-null, so you don't need to use `?` anymore.

---

You have a couple of variables to make - you want to make sure `pwc` isn't null, and also their `counterList`s. A quick way to do that is with `pwc?.counterList` - if `pwc` is null, it will return null. Otherwise it will move to the next step, and return `counterList`, which may be null. (Using `!!` is saying that it *definitely never will be null*, in which case it shouldn't be nullable at all!)

And you don't actually care about `pwc` anyway - you're just comparing its `counterList` to the other, so why don't we pare it back to just those?

```
val counters = counterList
val pwcCounters = pwc?.counterList
if (counters != null && pwcCounters != null) {
    try {
        for(counter: Counter in counters) {
            if(counter.counter_count != pwcCounters[
                pwcCounters.indexOf(counter)
            ].counter_count) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Hello")
            } else {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Goodbye")
            }
        }
    } catch(e: IndexOutOfBoundsException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

There's more we could do here, but just by cleaning up those nulls and using the specific variables we want to work with, does that feel easier to read? And more importantly, easier to understand what's happening and what *could* happen?

Might be worth throwing it in a function too, stops the call site getting cluttered with these temp variables:

```
fun doThing(counters: List<Counter>?, pwcCounters: List<Counter>?) {
    if (counters == null || pwcCounters == null) return
    // do the stuff
}

// when you want to do the thing:
doThing(counterList, pwc?.counterList)
```

So all your null checking is out of the way, your "temp variables" are the fixed parameters passed to the function, it's all nice and neat.

---

I know this is a long post for such a short bit of code, but it's a good habit to get into - if you're writing code where you're working with nullable `var`s and you're wrestling with the null safety system, or you keep repeating yourself to access a particular variable nested inside another object, you can make things a lot easier for yourself! You can imagine how wild this could all get for more complex code.

Also if you care, this is how I'd personally write it, if it helps!

```
fun doThing(counters: List<Counter>?, pwcCounters: List<Counter>?) {
    if (counters == null || pwcCounters == null) return
    // for (counter in Counters) is fine too I just like this version
    counters.forEach { counter ->
        // find returns the first item that matches the condition, or null if nothing matches,
        // so no need to handle any exceptions, just handle the potential null!
        // (this is a really common Kotlin pattern, lots of functions have a "returns null on failure" version)
        val pwcCounter = pwcCounters.find { it == counter }
        // remember pwcCounter can be null, so we have to use ? to access its count safely.
        // If it evaluates to null, the match just fails
        if (counter.count == pwcCounter?.count) Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Hello")
        else Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Goodbye")
    }
}
```

I also renamed `counter_count` to just `count` since it's a property on a `Counter` anyway. I feel like `counter.count` is easier to read than `counter.counter_count`, y'know? It's the little things